# python regex conditional in re.sub - how?

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

Is it possible to use python's regex conditionals in `re.sub()`? I've tried a number of variations without luck. Here's what I have.

```
import re
# match anything: <test> always true
a = re.compile('(?P<test>.*)')  

# return _'yes'_ or 'no' based on <test>
a.sub('(?(\g<test>)yes|no)', 'word')
'(?(word)yes|no)'
```

I expected either a 'yes' or 'no,' not the actual test.

What I get from this is that `<test>` is seen but the regex conditional isn't being executed. Is there another way of accomplishing this?

I tried with `re.sub(pat, rep, str)` with same results.

Comment: Could you add representative input text and desired output based on that?

Comment: I did. Input is 'word', desired output is 'yes'.

Comment: Under what circumstance would you expect 'no' to be printed? Note that the replacement parameter is never a regex. It is either 1) plain text; 2) a reference to a capture group or 3) a function reference.

Comment: It's interesting that the regex group is usable but the regex test is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to perform a conditional substitution, use a **function**
as the *replace* parameter.

This function accepts a *match* parameter (what has been caught)
and its result is the text to be substituted in place of the match.

To refer in the replace function to the capturing group named *test*,
use `group('test')`.

Example program:

```
import re

def replTxt(match):
    return 'yes' if match.group('test') else 'no'

a = re.compile('(?P<test>.+)')  
result = a.sub(replTxt, 'word')
print(result)
```

But I have such a remark:

There is no chance that `no` will ever be substituted by this program.
If the regex doesn't match, `replTxt` function will just not be called.

To have the possibility that *test* group matched nothing, but something
has been matched:

- this capturing group should be **conditional** (`?` after it),
- in order not to match an empty text, the regex should contain
  something more to match, e.g. `(?P<test>[a-z]+)?\d`.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_Bo.  This makes sense and is more readable than the path I was going down.