# How to perform this conditional regex replacement task, using lookarounds for bracket & quotation characters?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Currently I have this for my regex replacement:

```
import re
line = re.sub(r"\bstr\b", ":class:`str`", line)
```

I want a result like below, where the `<`, `>`, and ` stop replacement from occurring, and no replacement occurs if inside square brackets. I tried implementing negative lookarounds for just one of the characters, but I couldn't make it work.

Example input:

```
line = r"""list of str and list of :class:`str` or :class:`string <str>` or Union[str, Tuple[int, str]]"""
```

Example output of what I am aiming for:

```
"list of :class:`str` and list of :class:`str` or :class:`string <str>` or Union[str, Tuple[int, str]]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with negative lookbehind and negative lookahead.

```py
line = r"""list of str and list of :class:`str` or :class:`string <str>` or Union[str, Tuple[int, str]]"""
pattern = r"(?<![\[`<])(str)(?![\]`>])"
re.sub(pattern, r":class:`str`", line)
```

Output:

```
list of :class:`str` and list of :class:`str` or :class:`string <str>` or Union[str, Tuple[int, str]]
```

Check the Regex on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0nqG5H/1)

**UPDATE** on question in the comments.
Here is my conditional sub approach,
based on the idea of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52392221/15521392) approach by @Valdi_Bo

```py
line = r"""list of str and list of :class:`str` or :class:`string <str>` or Union[str, Tuple[int, str]]"""
pattern = r"\bstr\b"
def conditional_sub(match):
    if not line[match.start()-1] in ['[', '`','<'] and not line[match.end()] in [']', '`', '>']:
        return r":class:`str`"
    else:
        return r"~str"

re.sub(pattern, conditional_sub, line)
```

Output:

```
list of :class:`str` and list of :class:`~str` or :class:`string <~str>` or Union[~str, Tuple[int, ~str]]
```

`match.start()` and `match.end()` are just index numbers. With them we can check for the symbols before/after like in the pattern before and decide what to replace.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Would it be possible to add tilde ~ in front of the "str" like "~str" to the list of ignored cases?

Comment: not in one step (at least not in my knowledge). You could do the exact opposite pattern and sub `str` with `~str`

Comment: you're welcome. I will have another thought on this. If I come up with something, I'll update the answer :)